# iosとphp、cakePHPの連携について

Tags: ios, swift, php, cakephp

現在iOSでSNSを開発しています。
しかしサーバサイドを触るのが初めてなので難航しています。

クライアント（iOS）側からのサーバサイドへのリクエストはGETやPOSTなどで送られてくると思うのですが、それらのHTTPメソッドに対するリソース（URL）は、サーバサイド側で作成したリソースをクライアント側の開発者に教えておく必要があるということでしょうか？

変なこと言ってたらすいません。
説明がいまいちでしたら補足いたしますので、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

実行時になんらかの方法で動的にURLを解決するというのならそのルールを、
そうでなく、CakePHPのコントローラに対応するアクション呼び出しのURLが決まっているならばそのURLを、クライアントがそれらを知らないともちろんリクエストできません。

なおiOS9からだったかはデフォルトでSSL通信しか許可しなかったと思うので、HTTPではなくHTTPSでやりとりするのがいいでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
私としては後者の”CakePHPのコントローラに対応するアクション呼び出しのURLが決め、そのURLをクライアントに知らせる”といった方法でいこうと思っています。
その場合は、ルーティングを設定することでURLを設計していけばよいというのことでしょうか？